# Virtual Box Default save directory

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running a virtual machine on VirtualBox off of a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I'm wondering what directory the files of the virtual machine are saved in.

Comment: Do you mean where are the VM image files stored in Ubuntu, or are you asking where are the individual files from inside the virtual machine saved on your Ubuntu host machine?

Comment: The individual files from the VM

Comment: The individual files are not accessible from the host machine. Your virtual machine and all its contents are saved as one big image file on the host machine. You can not access the individual files and folders from outside the virtual machine.